# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: "Presta vers. 1.6.1.18

Tags: prestashop-1.6

My prestashop gives the following errors:

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getProducts() on null in /var/www/html/minie.dk/public_html/modules/productsbundle/productsbundle.php:181 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/minie.dk/public_html/classes/Hook.php(591): ProductsBundle->hookActionCartSave(Array) #1 /var/www/html/minie.dk/public_html/classes/Hook.php(546): HookCore::coreCallHook(Object(ProductsBundle), 'hookactionCartS...', Array) #2 /var/www/html/minie.dk/public_html/classes/Cart.php(214): HookCore::exec('actionCartSave') #3 /var/www/html/minie.dk/public_html/classes/controller/FrontController.php(327): CartCore->update() #4 /var/www/html/minie.dk/public_html/classes/controller/Controller.php(170): FrontControllerCore->init() #5 /var/www/html/minie.dk/public_html/classes/Dispatcher.php(367): ControllerCore->run() #6 /var/www/html/minie.dk/public_html/index.php(28): DispatcherCore->dispatch() #7 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/minie.dk/public_html/modules/productsbundle/productsbundle.php on line 181`

Can Anyone here see what the problem may be? And also, how to save it?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is related to your 'productsbundle' module when a product is added to the customer's shopping cart.

I would suggest either to update this module to the latest version available or to disable it from your admin panel.